# Как декомпилировать exe в py в 2021

Tags: python, pyinstaller

В общем есть 1 exe файл, а на нём что-то типо системы подписки, хочу через код её убрать и собрать обратно в exe. Единственная проблема - декомпилировать. У меня уже есть pyc, так-что единственная проблема это преобразование pyc в py. Кто-нибудь знает как это можно реализовать в 2021?
Про темы с uncompyle6 не писать, я большинство из них видел.

Answer (score 0):

Exe это в большинстве случаев pyc в zip. Зип распаковывается во временную папку при запуске, а pyc разбирается uncompyle6 и подобным, но в python 3.8 поменяли движек байткода и теперь все хакеры мира ждут новой версии.